# What teams have won the Champions League undefeated?

Tags: football, trivia, statistics, champions-league

With the Champions League finals coming this weekend, I was wondering if any team has ever won the Champions League or the European Cup without ever losing a game in both the Qualification rounds and Elimination rounds.

If it is a common occurrence, has any team ever won without conceding a goal, or accomplished that feat twice in a row?

Comment: BTW I thought that the term *clean sheet* is more frequently used to winning a match without conceding a goal. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutout#Association_football) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clean_sheet).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ten teams have won the European Cup/Champions League unbeaten, of which four have achieved this twice:

- Liverpool had 6 wins and 3 draws in [1980–81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1981_European_Cup_Final#Route_to_the_final) and 7 wins and 2 draws in [1983–84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_European_Cup_Final#Route_to_the_final).
- Milan had 5 wins and 4 draws in [1988–89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_European_Cup_Final#Route_to_the_final) and 7 wins and 5 draws in [1993–94](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_UEFA_Champions_League_Final#Road_to_the_final).
- Ajax had 7 wins and 2 draws in [1971–72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1972_European_Cup_Final#Route_to_the_final) and 7 wins and 4 draws in [1994–95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_UEFA_Champions_League_Final#Road_to_final).
- Manchester United had 5 wins and 6 draws in [1998–99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_UEFA_Champions_League_Final#Route_to_the_final) and 9 wins and 4 draws in [2007–08](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_UEFA_Champions_League_Final#Route_to_the_final).

The other clubs have achieved it on one occasion:

- Inter Milan had 7 wins and 2 draws in [1963–64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1964_European_Cup_Final#Route_to_the_final).
- Nottingham Forest had 6 wins and 3 draws in [1978–79](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1979_European_Cup_Final#Route_to_the_final).
- Red Star Belgrade had 5 wins and 4 draws in [1990–91](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1991_European_Cup_Final#Route_to_the_final).
- Marseille had 7 wins and 4 draws in [1992–93](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_UEFA_Champions_League_Final#Road_to_final).
- Barcelona had 9 wins and 4 draws in [2005–06](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_UEFA_Champions_League_Final#Route_to_the_final).
- Bayern Munich had 11 wins and 0 draws in [2019–20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_UEFA_Champions_League_Final).