# Undefeated Champions League Eliminations

Tags: football, trivia, champions-league

Are there any teams that have been eliminated in Champions League being undefeated?

What's the latest round of the competition that such a team has ever reached?

Comment: Related (to some extent): [What teams won Champions League undefeated](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13812/what-teams-won-champions-league-undefeated)

Comment: If you simply check Wikipedia articles on a few past Champions League finals, you can also see road to the final there. For example, [in 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) Atletico Madrid went unbeaten in the group stage (5 wins, 1 draw) and in knockout phase (3 wins, 3 draws) until they lost in the final after extra time.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: This team was eliminated in the final without being defeated *in regular time*. I guess that this does not count - you probably mean team eliminating after two draws based on [away goals rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Away_goals_rule). But clarifying this in your question would made your post a bit clearer. (There already was one answer - now deleted - which was made because the answerer ignored the away goals rule.)

Answer (score 5):

[Chelsea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014%E2%80%9315_Chelsea_F.C._season#UEFA_Champions_League) were the last team to go out of the Champions League without losing a match. It was during [2014-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014%E2%80%9315_UEFA_Champions_League) season.

[image]

this was their group stage performance.

[image]

the above one, their Round of 16 performance. They were out due to away goal.

So they exited Champions League without losing a match that season.

Comment: "The latest round" doesn't mean "the most recent to do so"; it's how far into the competition they got, the round they were eliminated in. But a good find anyway.

Answer (score 5):

There is one more case of a team eliminated unbeaten in the Champions League. Yet this didn't happen due to the away goal rule in the knock out stage, but after the group stage.

In Season 2002-03 AEK Athens participated in the third qualifying round and proceeded to the group stage with two wins, only to be knocked out after six consecutive draws in their six group matches.

So they were eliminated after a total of 2 wins - 6 draws - 0 defeats.

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002%E2%80%9303_UEFA_Champions_League#Group_C)

Comment: Can you provide a source or a record of the match?

Comment: I add the link to wikipedia source

Answer (score 2):

For questions like this, it might be reasonable to create a CW answer where users of this site might add occurrences they are able to find.

We are looking for teams which did not lose any game neither in group stage(s) nor in knockout phase, but were eliminated after two draws on [away goals rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Away_goals_rule).

**Round of 16**

- In [2008-09 season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008%E2%80%9309_UEFA_Champions_League) Atletico Madrid did lose neither in [group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008%E2%80%9309_UEFA_Champions_League#Group_D) nor in [knockout phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008%E2%80%9309_UEFA_Champions_League#Knockout_phase). They were eliminated by Porto after two draws in [Round of 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008%E2%80%9309_UEFA_Champions_League_knockout_phase#Round_of_16). (Atletico lost first leg in [third qualifying round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008%E2%80%9309_UEFA_Champions_League#Third_qualifying_round). But qualifying rounds usually are not counted in many CL statistics, so we can probably discount them here, too.)
- In [2014-15 season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014%E2%80%9315_UEFA_Champions_League) Chelsea lost neither in [group stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014%E2%80%9315_UEFA_Champions_League#Group_G) nor in [knockout phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014%E2%80%9315_UEFA_Champions_League#Knockout_phase). Chelsea was eliminated by Paris Saint-Germain in [round of 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014%E2%80%9315_UEFA_Champions_League_knockout_phase#Round_of_16). This has already been mentioned [in another answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14677/undefeated-champions-league-eliminations/14713#14713).

Comment: I will add that in [2001-02 season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001%E2%80%9302_UEFA_Champions_League#Knockout_stage) Manchster United reached semifinals without losing any match in knockout phase and in second group stage. But they had two loses in first group stage.